# How to write a file to external storage in Android 10 using Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-10.0, android-external-storage

File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(sdcard, "filename.txt");

Answer (score 0):

For API level 29 and above Use the ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT intent action to load the system file picker and allow the user to choose a location where to write the contents of a file. This process is similar to the one used in the "save as" dialogs that other operating systems use.
For further information please refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files) documentation.